# Ffmpeg Dll for php 5.6 ( x32 or x64)

Tags: php, dll, ffmpeg

I developed a project like a web tv . Users can upload videos and I get video info from php_ffmpeg.dll with ffmpeg_movie method. I was using php 5.5.12 and I've x32 and x64 php_ffmpeg.dll. Nowadays I want to upgrade my php version to 5.6 and changing wamp (apache , mysql ) to wpn-xm ( nginx , mariadb ).

I can find DLL for 5.2 5.3 5.4 5.5 , unfortunately 5.6 can not be found.

Please let me know that how can I build or find php ffmpeg dll for php 5.6 . I know how to use ffmpeg -i or ffprobe for getting video details but as I wrote there before , this is an existing web project . Therefore I could not change the basis .

Comment: I'm not sure what you're on about, but isn't it better to go native and use the executeable directly via `exec()`?

Comment: Hi Xorifelse, for new project I'm using json export from ffprobe, but this project, I have not enough time for changing ffmpeg_movie usage to the ffprobe :'(